# How to save an array of objects

Tags: android, android-preferences

So, I'm making a trivia game and so I created a custom array of questions. I have an xml file in the raw folder that holds all the questions, and parses everything into my array. I want to have the ability to shuffle all the questions after the user is done with a game and starts a new one.

This is really easy to implement - just shuffle the array! The problem I run into is saving things. With Shared Preferences, I can save the index (question the user was at) when they close the app. But when I shuffle the array, and they leave the app and go back in - the array is back to the default array so the shuffle is kind of moot. You obviously can't save arrays with shared prefs - so does anyone know a simple/easy way to save the shuffled array?

Answer (score 1):

Serialize and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: Right - I could do that. But...isn't it kind of overkill to go to all the work to serialize things just to save one array? Is there really no simpler alternative?